# Install fresh new Windows 10 installation from mounted iso?

Tags: installation, windows-10

It's possible to mount the Windows 10 iso in Windows 8.1 and perform a fresh install and not an update?

Comment: No;  You cannot mount the .ISO then perform the update.  You can use the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and select the option for it to perform the update.  You mounting an .ISO only works while Windows is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to upgrade first to ensure that you get the license correctly. After that you can go into Settings and choose to reset, or do a clean install later yourself.

Microsoft has released a [tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) that allows you to upgrade or create installation media.

You can find more information on the upgrading and installation process [here](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-do-a-clean-install-of-windows-10-1720775893).

Comment: Definitely, good idea. Although links are subject to change as well.

Comment: @MC10 What do you mean with ` or do a clean install later yourself`? i can't perform an installation with a USB drive because i don't have one, that's why i'm mounting the iso :)

Comment: Have you already upgraded? You don't have to do a clean install, you can just reset.

Comment: @Phoenix_uy - You an also use the Media Creation Tool and simply selection the option to perform the upgrade that way.  You have to perform the upgrade at least once, if you want the ability, to do a clean install.

Comment: Actually... I just did what I want. I mount the ISO and then I choose to not maintain any of the files, configurations, apps, etc and it worked perfectly!

Comment: @Phoenix_uy "and it worked perfectly!" --- I came here just to confirm this! Thanks! :D